# Why is my query slow for different dates when they are smaller datasets?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I wrote a TSQL query for a ad-hoc report that is reading off a very large table (500million records) that's indexed (clustered) on Date/Time.

The query runs terribly slow on certain date ranges versus others where it's lightning fast. I'm trying to figure out why it's doing that.

I took 2 sets of date ranges. One for (04-03-2014 to 04-04-2014) and the other for (05-03-2014 to 05-04-2014). Basically one month apart from both test results. The first range is fast, returning in a mere 10 seconds or so where the other hangs forever.

Looking at the data sets to see if one is significantly larger than the other, I analyze 2 tables in my query as a form of unit testing each segment. The TableA is the first table I'm selecting with the big data. TableB is the joined table later on the query where I LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB:

```
TableA (04-03) = 239,806 Records (1 Second Query Time)
TableB (04-03) = 6,569 Records (0 Second Query Time)

TableA (05-03) = 203,535 Records (8 Second Query Time)
TableB (05-03) = 3,388 Records (0 Second Query Time)
```

As you can see, TableA of the 04 date month is faster and more records than the TableA of the 05 date month, which has less records and slower times.

Now for the query itself, but I'm working on updating that. Here is some pseudo code:

```
CTE Query
  SELECT PRODUCTS (TableA - 100K+ Records)
     LEFT JOIN PRODUCT TABLE (1K Records)
  FILTERED BY [Time], LIKE Statement off LEFT JOIN
SELECT FROM ( --SUBQUERY
              SELECT FROM CTE Query
                LEFT JOIN SALES (TableB - 1K+ Records)
                JOIN ON [User-ID]
             )
PIVOT SUBQUERY (18 Columns in Pivot)
```

Product is indexed (Clustered) on [Time], which is used in the query.
Sales is joined on [Users-ID] which is NON-CLustered INDEX on SALES (TableB)
Bottleneck looks to be when I join SALES within the SUBQUERY.

**Optimizations**

I looked at the fragmented indexes to see if that was the cause. I noticed the product table has a 85% fragmented index that could be the cause on a NON-CLUSTERED. I rebuilt that last night and no change. The Sales table also had a smaller one that was rebuilt too.

Comment: Post the actual queries that you are posting the times for.  Check for different query plans.  Run a full dbccc checktable.  Don't post pseudo code if that is not part of question.  One question at a time.

Comment: Trying to convert it for use now. But the TableA/TableB analyzation is part of the pseudo code. I united tested each segement of the query to look at the SELECT statements the overall query is executing.

Comment: Please can you post the Actual Execution plan of the slow performing query along with the full query we can figure out what is taking the time?

Comment: You have a 4 times posted.  Please post the queries for each of those times.

Comment: I was going too, but the problem resolved itself after a complete rebuild of the clustered index and a SQL Server restart. I assume the date range I was querying was part of the fragmented index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilt the clustered index where there was a low percentage fragmented on disk. After rebuilding the index, I had to restart the SQL Server for an unrelated task and the query was running the same speeds on the bad date range as all other ranges. I will assume the fix is attributed to the rebuild of the index as that makes the most sense if the same query is faster with other date ranges than others where the record sets were larger.